Clifford module on spin manifolds
Intro: A complex vector bundle $\mathcal{E} \rightarrow M$ is a Clifford module if there is a Clifford action on it
$$
\begin{aligned}
c:\,  C^{\infty}\left(T^* M \otimes \mathcal{E}\right) & \rightarrow  C^{\infty}(\mathcal{E}) \\
v \otimes s & \mapsto c\left(v\right) s &
\end{aligned}
$$
satisfying the Clifford relation, i.e.,
$$
c\left(u\right) c\left(v\right)+c\left(v\right) c\left(u\right)=-2 g\left(u, v\right) .
$$
A Clifford connection on $\mathcal{E}$ is a connection $\nabla^{\varepsilon}$ compatible with the Clifford multiplication:
$$
\nabla_X^{\varepsilon}\left(c\left(v\right) s\right)=c\left(\nabla_X v\right) s+c\left(v\right) \nabla_X^{\varepsilon} s .
$$
Such a connection always exists, since it exists locally.
An example of Clifford module that exists on any manifold $M$ is simply the exterior algebra bundle $\mathcal{E}=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n \bigwedge^k T^*_p M$, where the Clifford action is given by
$$c(v)\omega=v\wedge\omega-\iota_v \omega,$$
where $\iota_v$ is the usual contraction defined via metric. It is then an easy exercise to show it satisfies the Clifford relation which we omit here. Now there is a theorem states that if $M$ is an even-dimensional oriented manifold with spinstructure, every Clifford module $\mathcal{E}$ is a twisted bundle $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{W} \otimes \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the spinor bundle. (c.f. N. Berline, E. Getzler, M. Vergne. Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators. Springer-Verlag, ed. 1992.). The proof is basically one-line, we just need to take $\mathcal{W}=\operatorname{Hom}_{C(M)}(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{E})$, and the isomorphism between $\operatorname{Hom}_{C(M)}(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{E}) \otimes \mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is given by $w \otimes s \mapsto w(s)$, where $C(M)$ means the homomorphism as between Clifford modules.
Now my question is,  in this specific example of the exterior algebra bundle on a spin manifold $M^{2n}$, do we generally have a way of writing down explicitly what is this $\mathcal W$? Or a bit more vaguely, do we generally have a relationship between sections of a spinor bundle and the differential forms? For example, in the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or the 2-sphere $S^2$, it can be shown that the there is a unique spin structure and the spinor bundle is the trivial, decomposing the exterior algebra bundle into odd and even parts, it is easy to show that here $\mathcal W$ is just the $\mathcal S$ itself. However I really do not know anything more than this actually.
